# Obfuscate RequireJS module name

Tags: node.js, requirejs, obfuscation

My project layout is:

```
-bin\
    -out.closeure.js // (compiled from out.js using the closure compiler)
    -out.js // this is the requirejs output file, no minification done)
-src\
    -lib\
        -library.js
    -main.js
    -somefile.js
```

Now when I use RequireJS to combine my project to a single file, is there a way to mangle the names of the module? For example in main.js instead of:

```
require(['somefile'], function(SomeFile){
    //blah
});
```

I'll have

```
require(['a6fa7'], function(SomeFile){
    //blah
});
```

Since I am using closure compiler to obfuscated everything, the only thing not being mangled is the module names, and I want to mangle that as well.

I looked at the https://github.com/stevensacks/grunt-requirejs-obfuscate plugin but it's not working and I'm not sure if that plugin does what I want.

Answer (score -1):

Edit1: I encourage to use instead [AMDclean](https://github.com/gfranko/amdclean), there may be no reason to keep the footprint amd produce on an optimized build. If you want to keep it, the following way is the workaround i made:
Use the `onBuildWrite` and `onBuildRead` as the documentation states:
`onBuildWrite` A function that will be called for every write to an optimized bundle of modules. This allows transforms of the content before serialization.

```
"replaceModuleNames": [],
//executed on every file read
onBuildRead: function(moduleName, path, contents){
    this["replaceModuleNames"].push({
        "name": moduleName,
        "with": makeid()
    });
    //Always return a value.
    return contents;
},
onBuildWrite: function (moduleName, path, contents) {
    console.log("moduleName: " + moduleName + " ,path: " + path + " ,contents: ... ");
    var text = contents;
    RegExp.escape = function(text) {
        return text.replace(/[-[\]{}()*+?.,\\^$|#\s]/g, "\\$&");
    };
    this["replaceModuleNames"].forEach(function(element){
        var regE = new RegExp('(?:define\\(|require\\().*(?:"|\')('+RegExp.escape(element["name"])+')(?:"|\')');
        text = text.replace(regE, function(a, b){
            return a.replace(b, element["with"]);
        });
        console.log("moduleName: "+moduleName+ " replaceWith: " + element["with"] + " result: " + text);
    });
    //Always return a value.
    return text;
}
```

Place it on the build.js, you have to implement `makeid` method,
i tested it but it might fail, so dont rely on it for production

Edit2: `text.replace(element["name"], element["with"]);` may cause inconsistent code, replaced with regexp groups, i am not experienced with regex so its open to improvements.

Comment: This will work only for toy cases. For real applications, good luck having it work right. `text.replace` is much too blunt a tool.

Comment: @Louis i made a broad answer, there is no reason for downvote

Comment: favor improvements over useless comments

Comment: Your regular expression is wrong. We're not talking about a subtle regular expression problem here, but about ignoring the variations of how `define` and `require` are actually used in general. Again, your code may work with a toy case, but won't work in general. However, ultimately, there is no amount of regular expression tweaking that will solve issue number 2 mentioned in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32440880/replace-module-ids-with-fake-names).

Comment: That case seems overkill to me, anyways dynamic calls to require through ajax work just fine using `dir` parameter with r.js, as they never get obfuscated